# To slither up (verb) in Italian (for a snake)

Tags: translation, vocabulary

What would you call to "slither up" in Italian?

It is a verb that describes vertical movement of a snake.

Image:
http://www.livescience.com/images/i/000/028/036/original/cover11.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&downsize=660:*

Suggestion: arrampicarsi.

Thank you.

Comment: This is the exact kind of questions to answer which dictionaries have been invented.

Comment: Maybe "ergersi".
It's not frequently used but I think it depends on the context.

Comment: @FrancescoCerofolini: Veramente “ergersi” significa “drizzarsi, elevarsi”...

Comment: The Oxford dictionary doesn't support a translation like "arrampicarsi”; I can't see hints for “vertical movement” in the description of the word.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the verb "strisciare" is an inaccurate translation. You can use it with the adverb "sopra" or the preposition "su" (translated with the word "up") to explain the movement of a snake slithering ON something. If you want to say that a snake is slithering UP something you have to use the verb "salire".
Ex.
Il serpente sta strisciando sull'albero. = The snake is slithering on the tree.
Il serpente sta salendo sull'albero. = The snake is slithering up the tree.

Sometimes you can hear the verb "arrampicare" referred to a snake but it's unformally used. In fact the verb "arrampicare/si (it's a reflexive verb)" should only be used for animals with arts as a direct translation of "to climb".